# Jquery button click to send AJAX request with Flask and Python

Tags: python, jquery, jquery-mobile, flask

I am trying to make a web application that accepts button clicks. The button clicked then sends a specific device, and operation code to the python application which then calls a irsend command using Lirc. This is based off of the source code/instructions from here:

https://github.com/slimjim777/web-irsend

http://randomtutor.blogspot.com/2013/01/web-based-ir-remote-on-raspberry-pi.html

The html for the button is simple and is in "Xbox.html"

```
<button onclick="clickedOp('Xbox', 'OnOff');"> Power </button>
```

This launches the js function:

```
<script>
function clickedOp(device_name, op) {
    $.ajax({url:'/' + device_name + '/clicked/' + op});
}
```

I know that the function is firing on a click event because if i put an alert command in the clickedOp function the alert command runs

the python/flask app looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request, redirect, url_for

BASE_URL = ''

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def menu():
    return render_template('menu.html')

@app.route("/<device_name>")
def remote(device_name):
    if device_name == "Xbox":
        return render_template('Xbox.html')


@app.route("/<device_name>/clicked/<op>")
def clicked(device_id=None, op=None):
    return render_template('test.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

All of the code up to the ajax request works. going to "/" loads the menu.html template and presents links to different devices, for instance

```
<a href="Xbox"> Xbox </a>
```

will route to

```
"/<device_name>"
```

in the python program and "Xbox.html" is loaded.
Then the button loads and clicking it fires the "clickedOp(device_name, op)" function.
This is where it breaks down. Even though the ajax request routes to

```
"/<device_name>/clicked/<op>"
```

the "test.html" page is not loaded

This is the case even though the Flask debugger says that there was a successful GET request(it returns 200) to "/Xbox/clicked/OnOff" (filling in the variables for the example above)

so any ideas why test.html is not being loaded from the ajax request, when it seems that in the source code/tutorial I provided he uses the same ajax method?

Comment: I would think that if you are seeing the HTTP 200 OK for the request to "/XBox/clicked/OnOff" then the Flask app is behaving correctly.  Your Jquery code is just firing an Ajax request - you haven't shown any response handlers.  Without them the page won't do anything when the response arrives.  Did you just leave them out of the code you posted?

Comment: @SteveAllison I am not doing anything with a response as no response is necessary to get the desired effect which is just to run the python function attached to the url sent by the ajax request which in turn runs a subprocess call in python just like the source code I linked to above. As far as I can tell he does nothing with any sort of response and doesnt even return a render_template command. The only reason I did was to test if it was running the python function at all because if it is then the template should render right? I only use ajax so the page doesnt have to reload for each click

Comment: In the code the template will render and be returned to the jquery Ajax object, which will do nothing with it - it won't render it in the browser.  Have you used your browser's developer tools to see if a response is received by the browser - again, if Flask logs HTTP 200 OK then I would imagine the request is being handled correctly.  You should also be able to put print statements in your Flask method and see them logged too (I think).

Comment: I see what you are saying. I was expecting the template to be rendered if the Flask method was running but it may in fact be running and returning it, but not displaying it unless i have the ajax request do something with the template that it gets back from the server. In that case it actually would run a subprocess call in the method which is what I need. Unfortunately I cant test this right now but I will asap, thanks!

Comment: No problem.  I get the impression it is a fun little project!

Comment: You were right. It was running the method. Put in the subprocess call and bam, clicking the buttons turned on the Xbox. I'm making a home automation system with the raspberry pi that responds to voice and a mobile website so it has been fun indeed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds great, are you writing it up anywhere?

Comment: I hopefully will be once its all completed if I have time before I go back to school. If so ill drop a link in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code the template will render and be returned to the jquery Ajax object, which will do nothing with it - it won't render it in the browser. Have you used your browser's developer tools to see if a response is received by the browser - again, if Flask logs HTTP 200 OK then I would imagine the request is being handled correctly. You should also be able to put print statements in your Flask method and see them logged too (I think).

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do this with help of AJAX... Here is a example which calls a python function which prints hello without redirecting or refreshing the page.

In app.py put below code segment.

```
//rendering the HTML page which has the button
@app.route('/json')
def json():
    return render_template('json.html')

//background process happening without any refreshing
@app.route('/background_process_test')
def background_process_test():
    print "Hello"
    return "nothing"
```

And your json.html page should look like below.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
      $('a#test').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $.getJSON('/background_process_test',
            function(data) {
             console.log(data)
        });
      });
    });
</script>


//button
<div class='container'>
<h3>Test</h3>
    <form>
        <a href=# id=test><button class='btn btn-default'>Test</button></a>
    </form>

</div>
```

Here when you press the button Test simple in the console you can see "Hello" is displaying without any refreshing.